# SSIS/SQL Server: Can I copy CDC prod data to look alike tables in the dev environment?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I don't know the inner workings enough to know whether this is even worth trying. The bottom line is I want to test a sampling of production data by writing a test SSIS package using the cdc component. Anyone out there done this?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315.aspx What do you mean by a sample of data? CDC is a complicated way to get a sample of data. It's probably easier to just restore a backup of prod and delete unwanted data. Then there is no load on the PROD database, you don't have to enable CDC, set up a SSIS package. CDC is for capturing changes to data - you don't want that, you just want a sample of data.

Comment: The prod tables have several hundred million rows, the cdc tables however only have about 70,000. I knew it was a long shot when I posted--however worth the ask. Right now I have t-sql scripts that generate prod-like data, however, the prod data itself would be the most useful--without trying to find space for a vldb.

Comment: Again, if the requirement is to get just a sample of rows, CDC is just complicating it. CDC is about capturing changes. I don't see anything in your requirements about capturing changes, just a requirement to get a sample of rows. You can do it that way if you want, it's just more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: The testing requires both subsets of changed data: new rows and existing rows that reflect activity against the db instance since the last execution.  I had the thought to point the connection strings to the production database, however, I do not want to loose the transaction record held in the prod version of the cdc tables.  Is there a way to configure CDC to not flag a touched transaction it is holding? That might be a practical alternative.

Comment: The technical term for what you want to do is add a 'subscriber' - you can have multiple subscribers that each have their own unique 'refresh' level. I can't tell you if SQL Server CDC or change tracking allows you to do this natively but there is always a home grown way to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need net changes, you can also consider Change Tracking instead of CDC as a more efficient option:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx

If it's only about generating test data I would recommend redgate's SQL Data Generator:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/